# Hyperledger Composer Installation

Tags: installation, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have tried installed hyper ledger composer CLI & its development tools but got errors. like the

```
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
```

npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated constantinople@3.0.2: Please update to at least constantinople 3.1.1
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/composer -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js

> pkcs11js@1.0.14 install /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/pkcs11js
>   node-gyp rebuild

sh: 1: node-gyp: Permission denied
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-24T02_16_27_676Z-debug.log
root@Composer:~# npm install -g composer-rest-server
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated constantinople@3.0.2: Please update to at least constantinople 3.1.1
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/composer-rest-server -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/cli.js

> pkcs11js@1.0.14 install /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-rest-server/node_modules/pkcs11js
>   node-gyp rebuild

sh: 1: node-gyp: Permission denied
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-24T02_16_58_032Z-debug.log
root@Composer:~# npm install -g generator-hyperledger-composer
npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated formatio@1.2.0: This package is unmaintained. Use @sinonjs/formatio instead

> pkcs11js@1.0.14 install /root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/generator-hyperledger-composer/node_modules/pkcs11js
>   node-gyp rebuild

sh: 1: node-gyp: Permission denied
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-03-24T02_17_21_569Z-debug.log

Whats the best way or single line command to install the composer on ubuntu ?

the i tried to install the cli as sudo user : got this error :

```
i tried to install the composer cli as sudo user: got this : "swap@composer:~$ npm install -g composer-cli
```

npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@1.0.0: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support
npm WARN deprecated crypto@0.0.3: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
npm WARN deprecated jade@1.11.0: Jade has been renamed to pug, please install the latest version of pug instead of jade
npm WARN deprecated transformers@2.1.0: Deprecated, use jstransformer
npm WARN deprecated constantinople@3.0.2: Please update to at least constantinople 3.1.1
npm WARN deprecated nodemailer@2.7.2: All versions below 4.0.1 of Nodemailer are deprecated. See https://nodemailer.com/status/
npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.9: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
npm WARN deprecated mailcomposer@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
npm WARN deprecated buildmail@4.0.1: This project is unmaintained
/home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/composer -> /home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/cli.js

> pkcs11js@1.0.14 install /home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/pkcs11js
>   node-gyp rebuild

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 13, in 
    import gyp
  File "/home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/**init**.py", line 8, in 
    import gyp.input
  File "/home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/input.py", line 5, in 
    from compiler.ast import Const
ImportError: No module named compiler.ast
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:336:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-109-generic
gyp ERR! command "/home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/bin/node" "/home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/swap/.nvm/versions/node/v8.10.0/lib/node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/pkcs11js
gyp ERR! node -v v8.10.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.1.3 (node_modules/composer-cli/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.14 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.14 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
"
please guide

Comment: Can you provide the commands you're using? This way we can investigate in a little more detail.

Comment: command i am using as sudo user : "npm install -g composer-cli"

Answer (score 1):

I would run a `npm update` and take a look at this two links:

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/installing-prereqs

and

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/reference/commands.html

Read with care about the requisites.
And I also notice the information:

> Please note: When using Ubuntu this command will fail when running in a root user shell.

Comment: As Felipe wrote - you need to read the instructions. https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/installing/installing-prereqs bullet 5 says "Do not use npm with sudo or su to root to use it". You also have an unsupported Node version (you need 8.9.x - use NVM to install). I would first do an `npm uninstall -g ` of the failed module(s) once Node is installed. Finally, read these first 3 items at https://github.com/mahoney1/composer-knowledge-wiki/blob/latest/knowledge.md#information_source--composer-installation-issues on NPM